# How can I make a SQLiteConnection object available to another method?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am attempting to to take a SQLiteConnection object in a SQLite connection method and make it available to a method used later on in my code.

```
private void SelectDbRecords()
{ 
    SQLiteConnection con;
    SQLiteDataAdapter da;
    SQLiteCommand cmd;
    DataSet ds;

    if (File.Exists("data.db"))
    {
        con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=data.db;Version=3;");
        SetConnection();
        con.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Sites";
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ...
```

How can I make this con object persist so I can access it later? I apologize if this is a silly question. Im learning C# and couldnt seem to find a clear answer on how to accomplish this. I tried using Friend but cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the con object globally inside the class so that you can access it later in any method of that class.

```
Public class classname
{
     SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=data.db;Version=3;");
     --Methods
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I really appreciate the help!